# django - getting value from a field which is hidden in html and using it in views file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, aptana

I am working in django and i want to set a value to a hidden field in html and use it in django view file

html file

```
<input type="hidden" id="t" name="t" />
<script>
document.getElementById('t').value = $('#SelectBox').selectit('t').join(', ');
</script>
```

My views.py is :

```
pos= request.POST.get('t')
```

this is how i am calling in the view file.

I also tried using

```
pos=request.POST('t')
```

but it does not seems to work. How can i do it? Am i doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try running the JS script tag after the "SelectBox" loads (ie putting it after html syntax of "SelectBox") or else an empty value is kept inside the "t"

Answer (score 0):

In your html file, you have written java-script without any event so how it will give any value to the hidden input field.

at the time of submitting Form, if there is not any value in your hidden input then it will not come in your view file and you will not get this "t" value. 
so first check at the time of event function, value is coming in your hidden input field then you can submit form and u will get t value in view file.